# Basis and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

How do i find the a basis and dimension for $A[x]$?

Consider the subset of $R[x]$ given by $A[x]:=\{q(x)$ element of $\mathbb R_4[x]$ such that $q(2)=0=q(-3)\}$

I'm a bit confused because there are two conditions to be satisifed, $q(2)=0=q(-3)$

Comment: Hint: every polynomial in $\mathbb R_4[x]$ can be written as a linear combination (with certain coefficients) of elements of your favorite basis for $\mathbb R[x]$, such as $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ perhaps. Express each equation $q(2)=0$ and $q(-3)=0$ as a linear equation in these coefficients. That should give you a system of linear equations, which you can solve in the usual way.

Comment: @GregMartin so does that mean I obtain two separate equations? One for q(2) and one for q(-3) and solve simultaneously?

Comment: You're not sure about the meaning of the terms in the question you are asking? Then isn't that something you should find out, before you ask the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson cheers for that comment brother

Comment: $A=B=C$ means: $A=B$ *and* $B=C$

Comment: Yes, you'll end up with a system of two linear equations. Perfect for linear algebra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following: one knows that a polynomial vanishes on a point $a$ iff it is a multiple of $(x-a)$. Because $(x-2)$ and $(x+3)$ are coprime polynomials, a polynomial vanishes on both $2$ and $-3$ iff it is a multiple of $(x-2)(x+3)$.

So, the subspace you're looking at is the space of polynomials of the form $(x-2)(x+3)p(x)$ of degree $4$. This last condition is equivalent to $\deg p \leq 2$.

In conclusion, (using my favourite basis for the space of degree $\leq 2$ polynomials), $(x-2)(x+3)$, $(x-2)(x+3) x$ and $(x-2)(x+3)x^2$ form a basis of your subspace.

Comment: mate, you're a legend @PseudoNeo